# how to embed swf file in ahref tag?

Tags: html, flash

i have an a href tag.
i want that embed swf (object) tag to a href.
i dont want add event in swf, beacuse a href link is different and create dynamic.
underestand it?
what can i do?

Comment: Didn't understand it clearly - you can clarify it.

Comment: You want to have a swf in TextField in <a> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Answer:

1.Process the html used in htmlText property of textField:
 - find and put `<a>...</a>` strings to Array

- check if Arrays strings have `<img ...>` strings inside them and put `{url:hrefFromString, img:idFromString, object:null}` to new Array

2.Create mouseDownHandler:

```
function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
   for(var i:uint = 0; i<array.length; i++){
      if(e.target == array[i].object){
         navigateToURL(new URLRequest(array[i].url));
   }
}
```

3.Add addEventListener Event.ADDED to textField with handler:

```
for(var i:int=0; i<array.length; i++){
   var dsp:Loader =  textField.getImageReference(array[i].img) as Loader;
   if(dsp!=null and array[i].object!=null){
      array[i].object = dsp;
      dps.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
      dsp.mousChildren = false;
   }
}
```

Finito! You don't only have mouseButton cursor.
Remember to add in html **id** for images!
Sample:

```
<a href='http://...'><img id='img1' src='...'></a>
```

Comment: thank you very much.
but i find a easy way.
i send a query string to swf file like:
file.swf?id=1234
and in flash with geturl, use this input varieble.